# MissingPlginException sqflite flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, sqflite

there is no problem when I run it on my own phone, but when I ctrl f5 with windows and emulator, I got such an error. It worked when I uninstalled the app from the emulator and ran it again. Why did this happen and how do I solve it in windows?
[image]

Comment: Do you run your application on the web or on the emulator of phone?

Comment: I had no problems when I ran it on my own phone. When I ran it with the emulator, it gave an error at first, but when I uninstalled the application from the emulator and ran it again, the problem in the emulator was resolved. But when I run it on windows the problem still persists.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you use this https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite package that doesn't support Windows application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use this package pub.dev/packages/sqflite that doesn't support Windows application right now.

Comment: Try to check this package: https://pub.dev/packages/moor